# Unable to export to excel in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsp, export-to-excel, weblogic12c

Below code is used to export html content into csv file.
It works fine locally in Firefox, IE and Chrome.
However when the application is pushed to Oracle Weblogic 12c server, it works in Firefox, IE but not Chrome.
Is there any setup or settings needed in server for it to works in Chrome?
There is no error message given, the downloaded csv file from Chrome is just blank.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    String fileName = req.getParameter("fileName");
    res.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();

    .... do whatever needed ....
}
```

---

**Update**

Funny things happen, the download feature suddenly not working for all browsers, only empty files are downloaded. In local, everything is fine. Can anyone suggest what settings is causing this behavior?